# Почему не скрывается модалка бутстрапа через селениум?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Ниже код действий. Модалка остаётся видима после клика на крестик закрытия окна. Я пробовал разные варианты, и через isDisplayed() и visibilityOf(). Этот вариант я нашёл в какой-то статье.

После close_btn.click(); можно добавить Thread.sleep(10); но, во-первых, это не поможет, а во-вторых есть же invisibilityOfElementLocated далее ко коду, которая должна подождать. 
НО! проблема решается добавлением того же слипа в самое начало closeModal(). Тогда всё ок, модалка скрыта. Как так-то? Что за дичь этот ваш селениум? Что за наркоманы его сделали?

Вот эксепшн который выдаётся, то есть модалка перекрывает мою нижнюю кнопку.

```
 И пользователь нажал на кнопку "Попробовать бесплатно" внизу страницы(Сценарий: На странице промосайта открывается окно регистрации с кнопок "Попробовать бесплатно"): Element <button class="btn btn-lg btn-lead btn-success"> is not clickable at point (674.4916
381835938,661.75) because another element <div id="sign-in" class="modal fade modal-signin show"> obscures it





package net.sitemech.steps.promo;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.ru.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PromoModalRegistrationSteps {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void prepareData() {
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setHeadless(true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //ждать 30 сек для загрузки страницы

    }

    @Допустим("^пользователь открыл страницу промосайта \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void setPage(String url){
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    @Когда("^пользователь нажал на кнопку \"Попробовать бесплатно\" вверху страницы$")
    public void clickBtnTop() {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".header [data-toggle=\"modal\"]"));
        element.click();
    }
    @То("^отобразится модальное окно \"Попробуйте бесплатно\"$")
    public void modalIsShown() {
        WebDriverWait  wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,4);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("sign-in")));
    }

    @Когда("^пользователь нажал кнопку \"X\" на модальном окне$")
    public void closeModal() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement modal = driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in"));
        WebElement close_btn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sign-in .close"));
        System.out.println("modal:" + modal.isDisplayed());
        close_btn.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("modal:" + modal.isDisplayed());
    }
    @И("^пользователь нажал на кнопку \"Попробовать бесплатно\" внизу страницы$")
    public void clickBtnBottom() {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".footer [data-toggle=\"modal\"]"));

        element.click();
    }
    @То("^снова отобразится модальное окно \"Попробуйте бесплатно\"$")
    public void modalIsShownAgain() {
        WebDriverWait  wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,4);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("sign-in")));
    }

    @After
    public void clearData() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Если коротко, то вся магия тут:

```
System.out.println("modal:" + modal.isDisplayed());
close_btn.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("modal:" + modal.isDisplayed());
```

В первом выводе я ожидаю true (приходит true) во втором ожидаю false (приходит true). Но если добавить *Thread.sleep(5000)* ПЕРЕД кликом, то всё сработает как надо.

Comment: что значит "всегда" видима после закрытия?   если есть исключения в логе, то приложите к вопросу.

Comment: Я имел ввиду есть клик по кнопке "Х" (крестик) в модалке бутстрапа. И после его нажатия (никаких эксепшенов) модалка не скрывается (см. в задаче "всегда видима", согласен, кривая фраза "после закрытия") и println в обоих случаях выводит true. Сейчас подправлю пример для более точного исключения

Comment: может быть кнопка становится активной и доступной после того, как на нее навели мышку?

Comment: @senior-pomidor нет, это же стандартный контрол. И Thread.sleep тогда бы не помогал до клика

Comment: Я так же пробовал `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#sign-in .close"))); `